# printf(my_func,"My string");

Tags: c

What does the function before the "Mystring" do? I don't understand how do we pass a function inside printf function. Can you explain me what the role of that function is and why/when we use it? Thank you!

Comment: If `my_func` is actually a function, this code is totally invalid. You can't use a function pointer as a string.

Comment: You'll need to show the declaration for `my_func`

Answer (score 2):

**Official answer:**

Undefined behavior by the C-language standard.

**Practical answer:**

The prototype (declaration) of `printf`:

```
int printf(const char* str,...);
```

So if you emit compiler warnings, then you can call `printf` with pretty much any arguments you like, just as long as the first argument that you pass can be implicitly converted to a `char` pointer.

By calling `printf(my_func,"My string")`, it will attempt to print a null-terminated array of characters, located at the address of function `my_func` in memory.

Since every function must reside at a memory section with read-access permission, there should be no problem to begin with.

The only question remaining is, will a `'\0'` character appear somewhere after this address, but within the readable memory section (i.e., before `printf` attempts to access non-readable memory).

An additional problem may occur if `printf` encounters a `'%'` character along the way, in which case, it will attempt to print the next argument (`"My string"`) but not necessarily in the expected format.

The problem will get worse if `printf` encounters more `'%'` characters further ahead, since no additional arguments have been passed to it.

Comment: The only way it's undefined is if the function doesn't return a `const char *`, right? If it does, then it would be perfectly acceptable to my knowledge.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner: No, take a closer look. It's not a function-call, it's just the address of the function (in other words, it is not `printf(my_func(),"My string")` there).